# Does testing a training dataset guarantee successful results?

Tags: machine-learning-model, training

If I test an image that has been previously used to train a classification model, is it **guaranteed** to classify correctly?

My guess is that since the parameters have been trained with other images as well, there is no guarantee of getting a correct classification, just a high probability.

Comment: This is correct, there's no guarantee at all, not even a high probability. As usual It depends on the type of model, the data, the number and distribution of the classes.

Comment: Thank you @Erwan! Do you mind posting this comment as an answer, so that I can accept?

Comment: Ok let's not be lazy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct, there's no guarantee at all, not even a high probability. As usual It depends on the type of model, the data, the number and distribution of the classes.

However there's of course a higher *chance* that the instance would be correctly classified. That's why one shouldn't use a test set containing training instances to estimate the performance of the model, since there's a high risk the performance would be overestimated ([data leakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leakage_(machine_learning))).